A finite dimensional continuum with a subset $A$ such that both $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are dense and contractible
Inspired by this  question we  ask the  following  question.
Note that the  comment  conversation and  answers  to the  above  question imply that

There are  two  complementary subsets of the  unit  sphere of  $\ell^2$ which  are  contractible  and dense.

I  wonder  if this  situation mentioned  above  can  hold  for  a  finite  dimensional  continuum
Namely:

Is there  a  finite  dimensional  continuum $X$ which  possesses a  subset $A$  such that both $A$  and  $X\setminus  A$ are  dense  and  contractible?


Does this qualify as example: $X:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $A:=(\mathbb Q\cap[0,1])\times[0,1)\cup[0,1]\times{0}$ ?

A  further question:  can e.g. the unit  ball of $\mathbb R^2$   be decomposed into 3    dense contractible sets ?

@PietroMajer  Thanks  for  your  comment  and  very interesting  answer

@PietroMajer  An  amazing point:  A telepathy:  I was thinking  to the  same question and assigning a  natural number $n$ as the  maximum valuse of the  number of  partition of  a  continum: Then I thought that re your  example  in  comment  possibly can be reconstructed to 3 partition. If  we  can  write  $Q$  as  disjoint union of  two  dense  subset...and apply it to $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$  but I realized this idea  does not  work  since we  have  a  connected interval at the  ground

@PietroMajer  So  it is unlike  that one  produce a 3 partition. does  this define  a  topological invariant somewhat related to dimension theory?

A  fancy decomposition  of the closed unit disk $X$ of $ \mathbb{C}$  into two dense contractible sets.  Let $D_1$, $D_2$ be a $2$-partition of the interval $[0,1]$ into dense sets. Consider the disjoint sets:
$A_1:= \{z\in X \setminus[-1,0) :|z|\in D_1\} \cup(0,1]  $
$A_2:= \{z\in X \setminus(0,1]  :|z|\in D_2\} \cup[-1,0)  . $
Both are dense and contractible , and $X=A_1\cup A_2$.

Very  interesting answer  Thank  you  very  much. I  guess  in  definition of  $A_2$ you  mean  $D_2$ . the  contractibility  then  comms from the  contractibility of logarithm branch.
